# RxJs Debounce does not emit any value

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

As far as I understand, `debounce` `keeps track of the most recent value from the source Observable, and spawns a duration Observable by calling the durationSelector function`

I have the following code

```
    import { interval } from 'rxjs';
    import { debounce } from 'rxjs/operators';

    const data = interval(1000);

    const silenceTimer = interval(2000);
    data.pipe(debounce(val => silenceTimer)).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

I expect it will emit 1, 3, 5,etc., but it does not emit any value at all. 
Do I understand the operator correctly or did I do something wrong.
Thank you

EDIT:
I understand why no value is emitted now! because the interval 2000 is greater than the generation interval 1000, so all values are thrown away. If I reduce the debouncing interval to 500, all values will be emitted

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/debounce):

> `debounce()` Emits a value from the source Observable only after a particular time span determined by another Observable has passed without another source emission.

Note the phrase: *without another source emission*.  In your case interval will keep generating emissions within the 2000ms of your durationSelector, so `debounce()` never gets a chance to emit.

Comment: If you look at the example at the bottom of the link you cited, you will see that the interval is used to emit the last value

Comment: Yes, that's not the interval call I was referring to.  The interval within `data` will keep generating emissions within the 2000ms of your durationSelector (a second interval), so `debounce()` never gets a chance to emit.